# Disable throttling and cache eviction in Microsoft AppFabric?

Tags: caching, appfabric, appfabric-cache

So I had been planning on using AppFabric as a location to pre-cache some very expensive queries for other clients to pull from and discovered the throttling feature

I'd like to use a permanent in-memory data-store and thought AppFabric would do the trick, but it appears as though it might not...

Any suggestions on disabling throttling and cache eviction in AppFabric - or - any recommendations on an in-memory 'cache' servce for Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppFabric Caching provides an in-memory, distributed cache platform for Windows.

Expiration and eviction could be disabled in the cache config.

```
<dataCache size="Small">
    <caches partitionCount="32">
        <cache consistency="StrongConsistency" name="default" minSecondaries="0">
            <policy>
                <eviction type="None" />
                <expiration defaultTTL="10" isExpirable="false" />
                <serverNotification isEnabled="true" />
                <backingStore>
                    <writeBehind retryInterval="300" />
                </backingStore>
            </policy>
        </cache>
    </caches>
<dataCache/>
```

One tool to easily test this feature is [GUI Administrator for Appfabric 1.1](https://appfabricadmin.codeplex.com/)

Note that it is not always recommanded to disable Throttling because when physical memory becomes low on a cache host, attempts to write to the cache will generate exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for that
I since uninstalled AppFabric and installed Couchbase Memcached which I find a lot easier to use/manage